# How to convert array with only one element to object in mongoose(mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use KeystoneJs so the grammar is a little different with typical mongoose, I believe you can understand it with ease. My query function shows as below.

```
CourseResourceUnlock.model.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        $and: [{ inviter: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(inviter) }, { courses: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(course) }]
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: '$invitees'
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'users',
                        localField: 'invitees',
                        foreignField: '_id',
                        as: 'invitees',
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        invitees: {
                            $elemMatch: {
                                isVerified: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: '$_id',
                        inviter: { $first: '$inviter' },
                        courses: { $first: '$courses' },
                        invitees: { $push: '$invitees' },
                        term: { $first: '$term' },
                        universityYear: { $first: '$universityYear' },
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        invteesNumber: {
                            $size: '$invitees'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $sort: {
                        invteesNumber: -1
                    }
                },
                {
                    $limit: 1
                }
            ]).exec((err, data) => {
                if (err) return res.apiError('database error', err);
                return res.apiResponse(data);
            });
```

It can return the correct content of data but format in some parts seems not. Data returned shows as below:
[image]

The invitees field should contain 3 objects (as invitee). However, each invitee is an array with only one item now. Where is my mistake in the aggregate function? How could I convert the single element array to an object in backend?

Actually the returned data itself is also a single element array.

Collection definition shows as below, it is also written in keystonejs style.

```
CourseResourceUnlock.add({
inviter: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User' },
courses: {
    type: Types.Relationship,
    ref: 'Course',
    many: true,
},
invitees: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User', many: true },
universityYear: { type: String, default: currentYear },
term: { type: Types.Select, options: '1,2,3' }});
```

The mistake is on `invitees` field, what I expacted is an array seems like `[{...},{...},{...}]` However, it is `[[{...}],[{...}],[{...}]]`now

Comment: can you post some sample document of both collection and expected result.

Comment: try adding this `{ $unwind: "$invitees" }` stage before `$group` stage.